# Pass Azure AD Token for Azure SQL DB in pre-connection arguments to SQLAlchemy create_engine()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I'm wanting to connect to an Azure SQL DB via SQLAlchemy with an AD token.

I've followed https://github.com/felipefandrade/azuresqlspn and can successfully connect with this method. However, I want to extend this and use SQLAlchemy to manage the connection.

```
from os import environ
import struct
import adal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc

clientSecret = environ.get('clientSecret')
clientID = environ.get('clientID')
tenantID =  environ.get('tenantID')
authorityHostUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"
authority_url = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenantID
resource = "https://database.windows.net/"
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url, api_version=None)

token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    resource,
    clientID,
    clientSecret)


tokenb = bytes(token["accessToken"], "UTF-8")
exptoken = b''

for i in tokenb:
    exptoken += bytes({i})
    exptoken += bytes(1)

tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken

driver = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"
server = ";SERVER={0}".format(environ.get('server'))
database = ";DATABASE={0}".format(environ.get('database'))

connString = driver + server + database

SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256
conn = pyodbc.connect(connString, attrs_before={SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct})

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 ID, Name FROM [Table1]")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print("######")
print("Using pyodbc directly - This works")
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

print("#####")
print("Connecting via sqlalchemy - This doesn't work")
SAconnString = "mssql+pyodbc://<server>.database.windows.net/<database>?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
db = create_engine(SAconnString, connect_args={'attrs_before': {SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct}})

SAconn = db.connect()
result = SAconn.execute("SELECT TOP 20 ID, Name FROM [Table1]")
for row in result:
    print(row['ID'] + " " + row['Name'])
```

As noted in the code, using `pyodbc.connect()` method will work. However, using SQLAlchemy I get the error `FA005] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot use Access Token with any of the following options: Authentication, Integrated Security, User, Password`. It appears to me the `connect_args` option is passing the token through, but with other options too. How do I get SQLAlchemy to correctly pass the AD Token to pyodbc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to send PyODBC connection string explicitly with `urllib`.

```
connString = driver + server + database
params = urllib.parse.quote(connString)
db = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={0}".format(params), connect_args={'attrs_before': {SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct}})
```

Comment: Nowadays, you can also use `snowflake.engine.URL.create` to construct the url for `create_engine`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this code using SQLAlchemy :

```
import sqlalchemy
import urllib
import pyodbc


params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:***.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Mydatabase;Uid=ServerAdmin@***;Pwd=***;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;")

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params, connect_args={'attrs_before': {SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct}})
conn=engine.connect()
print(conn)

result = conn.execute("select * from tb1")
for row in result:
    print(str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
conn.close()
```

I get the connection string from portal:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that actually work? [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-2017#authenticating-with-an-access-token) states you can't send UID, PWD or TrustedConnection when using token authentication. Otherwise, yeah I figured out you need to use `urllib.parse.quote()`.

Comment: Isn't the challenge here to do everything in code and avoid using password/user?

Comment: You can specify UID, PWD for TrustedConnection - they will be simply ignored.