# SqlAlchemy connect to Azure Postgresql Flexible Database with token authentication

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-active-directory, pyodbc, azure-database-postgresql

I would want to connect `SqlAlchemy` to `Azure Database for Postgres` with `token based authentication` to achieve Single Sign On (SSO) by using Azure Active Directory (AAD), but seems like SqlAlchemy poorly support token-based connection string, is there any way to achieve it? In my solution, SqlAlchemy is required, and Single-Sign-On with Azure AD is required, and no password provided.

I browsed and it seems like pyodbc library work with token auth, [pyodbc lib token auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61882384/15538104), but I need SqlAlchemy, it's very cutting-edge case, I believe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Azure AD Token for Azure SQL DB in pre-connection arguments to SQLAlchemy create\_engine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193301/pass-azure-ad-token-for-azure-sql-db-in-pre-connection-arguments-to-sqlalchemy-c)

Comment: @rfkortekaas It's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the procedure below to connect to an Azure Database for PostgreSQL server using access token authentication:

Use the code below to get the access token for authentication:

```py
import msal

# Define Azure AD settings
client_id = "<clientId>"
client_secret = "<clientSecret>"
tenant_id = "<tenantId>"
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority
)

result = None
try:
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)
    if not result:
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(ex)}")

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
    print(access_token)
else:
    print(f"Token acquisition failed: {result.get('error')}")
```

Use the code below to connect to the Azure Database for PostgreSQL server using SQLAlchemy:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import urllib.parse

# Replace these placeholders with your PostgreSQL server details
username = "<activeDirectoryName>"
hostname = "<serverName>.postgres.database.azure.com"
port = "<port>"
database_name = "<databaseName>"

# Properly percent-encode the password
password_encoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(access_token)

# Create the database URL
db_url = f"postgresql://{username}:{password_encoded}@{hostname}:{port}/{database_name}"

engine = create_engine(db_url)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    query = text("SELECT usename AS role_name FROM pg_catalog.pg_user ORDER BY role_name desc;")
    result = connection.execute(query)

    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

Below is the complete code:

```py
import msal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import urllib.parse

# Define Azure AD settings
client_id = "<clientId>"
client_secret = "<clientSecret>"
tenant_id = "<tenantId>"
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority
)

result = None
try:
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)
    if not result:
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(ex)}")

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result["access_token"]
else:
    print(f"Token acquisition failed: {result.get('error')}")

# Replace these placeholders with your PostgreSQL server details
username = "<activeDirectoryAdmin>"
hostname = "<serverName>.postgres.database.azure.com"
port = "<port>"
database_name = "<database>"

# Properly percent-encode the password
password_encoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(access_token)

# Create the database URL
db_url = f"postgresql://{username}:{password_encoded}@{hostname}:{port}/{database_name}"

engine = create_engine(db_url)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    query = text("SELECT usename AS role_name FROM pg_catalog.pg_user ORDER BY role_name desc;")
    result = connection.execute(query)

    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

You will get the output as mentioned below:

[image]